# Matlab find range of periodicity of signal

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have a signal that is periodic in some places and not in others, and I want to be able to find the range(in time) where it is periodic. I cannot show my original signal here, but I'll use an example signal to illustrate my questions:

Example signal:

```
vect=[randn([1,500]) sin(x) 1:500]; 
x=linspace(0, 20*Pi, 1000)
```

I want something that will tell me that the signal is periodic for x between 500 and 1500, basically.

I tried using the `xcorr` function (I used `xcorr(y,'unbiased')` and then found the zero lag peak and found other peaks that were within a certain % of the zero lag to define the region of periodicity but I can't figure out how to relate the lags back to the x range.

EDIT: Code I'm using so far

```
    [c, lags] = xcorr(y,'unbiased');
    lag_zero=find(lags==0)
    [peaks,locs]=findpeaks(c,'MINPEAKHEIGHT',.5*c(lag_zero)); %finding peaks 
    cindex=find(((c(lag_zero)-(0.5*c(lag_zero)))<c) & (c<(c(lag_zero)+(0.5*c(lag_zero)))));
    maxlags=lags(max(cindex));
    [c2,lags2]=xcov(y,y,maxlags,'unbiased'); %this is just to narrow the periodic part down
    plot(lags2,c2);
    period=abs(x(locs(floor((length(locs))/2)))-x(locs(floor(((length(locs))/2)-1))))
```

Comment: could you share the code you have so far?

Comment: I added it, though it's not much.

Comment: Is the frequency known?

Comment: In this case, the frequency should be 2*pi but in general I'm trying to find the period to figure out the frequency.

Comment: The problem with using xcorr in this way is that is you're comparing the entire signal to itself, so it says nothing about which part of the signal contains the periodicity. You can see this by changing your sample "vect" to put the sin(x) part at the front or at the end, and looking at what result you get out of xcorr - it will be close to the same.

Comment: Is there a better way you could suggest? I am new to signal processing in general.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest place to start would be to window the data and then use a technique like [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/993-lombscargle-m) to find frequencies which have power above a certain noise floor.  This analysis is a lot like seasonality, but with a different period, but that's not a problem.  Check out [this link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16117/what-method-can-be-used-to-detect-seasonality-in-data) from Cross Validated.

Comment: I think my issue is more that I want the range of periodicity as well as the frequency than just the frequency. But thank you for those directions

Answer (score 0):

Run `[~,F,T,P] = spectrogram(vect, 128, 120, 128, 1)` and you get
[image]

With a visual inspection you see that between elements 500 and 1500 you have a monochromatic signal. You can inspect `P`for a rectangular area with very low values, probably better use `10*log10(P)`, and use `F` and `T` to extract the interval and the frequency.

Comment: In a spectrogram, does a monochromatic area always correspond to a range where the signal is periodic?